# gitlab undefined method add visibility level

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-8

I've just updated our GitLab server (gitlab-ce package on CentOS) from 8.5.8 to 8.9.6, but I've got a problem with the database migration while it's going through the reconfigure.

I've thrown the full trace on to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/W1AvYi2x

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Code included, I ran the rake command this time rather than the full reconfigure.

```
# gitlab-rake db:migrate

== 20160301124843 AddVisibilityLevelToGroups: migrating =======================
-- add_column(:namespaces, :visibility_level, :integer, {:null=>false, :default=>20})
   -> 0.0985s
-- add_index(:namespaces, :visibility_level)
   -> 0.0057s
-- select_one("SELECT restricted_visibility_levels FROM application_settings ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
   -> 0.0005s
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20160301124843_add_visibility_level_to_groups.rb:9:in `up'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:611:in `exec_migration'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `ddl_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
NoMethodError: undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20160301124843_add_visibility_level_to_groups.rb:9:in `up'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:611:in `exec_migration'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `ddl_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: Please include any relevant code or error message directly in your post.

Comment: That code has now been added!

Comment: I've ended up downgrading back to 8.5.8 which also meant I had to delete the .rdb file so GitLab would start. [related](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1401)